# How to retrieve deeply nested array based on some specific criteria spring mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a Collection called abc (let's assume), in this collection i have multiple documents having structure like:

```
{
   "customerId":"Id",
   "contract":[
      {
         "contractId":"con1",
         "contractName":"conName1",
         "pricing":[
            {
               "pricingName":"priceName1",
               "billProfile":[
                  {
                     "billCode":"code1",
                     "billName":"Name1"
                  },
                  {
                     "billCode":"code2",
                     "billName":"Name2"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "pricingName":"priceName2",
               "billProfile":[
                  {
                     "billCode":"code3",
                     "billName":"Name3"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "contractId":"con2",
         "contractName":"conName2",
         "pricing":[
            {
               "pricingName":"priceName3",
               "billProfile":[
                  {
                     "billCode":"code4",
                     "billName":"Name4"
                  },
                  {
                     "billCode":"code5",
                     "billName":"Name5"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "pricingName":"priceName4",
               "billProfile":[
                  {
                     "billCode":"code6",
                     "billName":"Name6"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

For multiple documents like these, i want to search for a particular billcode and then return the corresponding billProfile, pricing and contract details for that bill code. For example if i search for billCode code5 then the corresponding output from the database should be:

```
{
   "customerId":"Id",
   "contract":[
      {
         "contractId":"con2",
         "contractName":"conName2",
         "pricing":[
            {
               "pricingName":"priceName3",
               "billProfile":[
                  {
                     "billCode":"code5",
                     "billName":"Name5"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**What I've tried so far:**

Using positional operator $ but it can be used for going only one level deeper into the document.Tried retrieving that particular contract having billCode but wrong pricing and billprofile are also included in the result set.

I know we can use aggregation for this thing but i've no idea how to perform aggregation on such complex retrieval. I need to use aggreagtion in my java spring project to fetch the data from database and then store it in my class model. Any idea how to perform aggregation on this data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$filter` and `$map` for the same.

Note: I have not tested in Java. But its work in `MongoDB GUI`

```
db.getCollection('customer').aggregate([ 
{ "$project": {
    "_id":1,
    "customerId" :1,
    "contract": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$contract",
            "as": "con",
            "in": {
              "pricing": {
                "$filter": {
                 "input": {
                    "$map": {
                  "input": "$$con.pricing",
                  "as": "pric",
                   "in" : {
                     "billProfile" : {
                       "$filter" : {
                         "input" : "$$pric.billProfile",
                          "as" : "billProf",
                          "cond": {
                                "$eq": [ "$$billProf.billCode", "code5" ] 
                            }

                       }
                     }
                   }
                }
                 },
                 "as": "pric",
                  "cond": {
                    "$and": [
                      { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$$pric.billProfile" }, 0 ] }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }             
            }
          }
       },
       "as": "con",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [
            { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$$con.pricing" }, 0 ] }
          ]
        }
      }
     }
    }
  }
]
)
```

Comment: Can you explain the flow of the pipelines?

Comment: Please read : `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/` for `filter`

Comment: For `map` look into `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/`